# Arquivo html+css(bootstrap) quando inserido pelo "require_once()" do php não funciona o menu dropdown

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Estava criando o menu do meu sistema e estava tudo funcionando corretamente, o arquivo menuHorizontal.php contem o menu e nele tem um dropdown que estava funcionando, quando eu clico, ele abre o submenu, até ai tudo bem, o problema é que agora no arquivo index.php, eu coloquei la na linha 2 o `require_once("menuHorizontal.php")`; e indo no index.php, o menu aparece certinho o problema é quando eu clico no dropdown, ele não desce, funciona a função "hover" que eu coloquei, porém o dropdown não desce. Alguma ideia de algo?

index.php

```
<?php
require_once("menuVertical.php");
require_once("menuHorizontal.php");
?>

<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head>
    <title>Menu</title> 
</head> 
<body>  
</body>
</html>
```

menuHorizontal.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head>
    <title>Menu</title> 
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.1.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/menu_js.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/menu_style.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="css/jquery-2.0.0.min.js" /></script>
    <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!--[if IE 7]>
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.1.1/css/font-awesome-ie7.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <![endif]-->

</head>
    <div class="longBarHorizontal">
    <!-- INICIO DO HEADER HORIZONTAL -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" style="margin-left: 300px; min-height: 40px; height: 41px;">
      <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color: rgb(49, 50, 64);">
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"> 
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li style="height: 45px; margin-top: -5px;">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style="height: 45px;">               
                    <span>Requisições</span><i class="icon-caret-down"></i>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-cart" role="menu" style="max-height: 85vh; overflow-x: hidden;">
                  <li> 
                    <span class="item"> 
                        <span class="item-left">
                            <span class="item-info"> 
                                <span> <b>Paciente:</b> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </span> 
                                <span> <b>Requisição N°:</b> 220 </span>
                                <span> <b>Atendimento N°:</b> 4933 </span>
                                <span> <b>Setor Solicitante:</b> Emergência </span>
                            </span>
                        </span>
                    </span>

                    <hr style="margin: 10px;">
                    <span class="item"> 
                        <span class="item-left">
                            <span class="item-info"> 
                                <span> <b>Paciente:</b> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </span> 
                                <span> <b>Requisição N°:</b> 222 </span>
                                <span> <b>Atendimento N°:</b> 9844 </span>
                                <span> <b>Setor Solicitante:</b> Ambulatorial </span>
                            </span>
                        </span>
                    </span>
                    <hr style="margin: 10px;">
                  </li>
                  <!--<li class="divider"></li>-->
                  <li><a class="text-center" href="" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">Ver Todas</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
<!-- FIM DO HEADER HORIZONTAL -->
    </div>
<body>  
</body>
</html>
```

javascript

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('ul.form li a').click(
        function(e) {
            e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default action
            e.stopPropagation; // stop the click from bubbling
            jQuery(this).closest('ul').find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
            jQuery(this).parent().addClass('selected');
        });
});
```

Comment: No devtools ou equivalente aparece algum erro no console quando você clica no dropdown? Mostre a parte do javascript.

Comment: O javascript dele é bem pequeno, inclui na pergunta.

Comment: E tenho a seguinte informação também: Além do dropdown não funcionar, eu coloquei um href="https://www.google.com"  e mesmo assim não funcionou, não abriu o dropdown e não abriu o link do google. É como se estivesse "desabilitado", clica mas não acontece nada.

Comment: E também tenho a seguinte informação: Se eu abrir uma tag php e colocar um "echo" por exemplo, o dropdown funciona, se eu colocar um "include" que inclua um arquivo simples, apenas um HTML escrito "teste", o dropdown também funciona. Estou imaginando que o problema possa ser incluir um arquivo com códigos característicos do bootstrap, no meu caso, o "menuVertical.php".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema aconteceu por incluir o arquivo menuVertical.php que continha os seguintes comandos dentro das tags `<head></head>`

```
<head>
<title></title> 
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.1.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/menu_style.css" />


<!--[if IE 7]>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.1.1/css/font-awesome-ie7.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<![endif]-->
```

Esses comandos existiam no arquivo menuHorizontal.php e no arquivo menuVertical.php e isso estava ocasionando um conflito. A solução foi remover esse bloco de códigos de um dos arquivos.